# accepts_nested_attributes_for ignore blank values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-attributes

i have

```
class Profile
  has_many :favorite_books, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :favorite_quotes, :dependent => :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :favorite_books, :allow_destroy => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :favorite_quotes, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

I have a dynamic form where you press '+' to add new textareas for creating new favorites. 
What i want to do is ignore the blank ones, I find this harder to sort through in the update controller than a non nested attribute.

What i have temporarily is a hack in the after_save callback deleting the empty records. Whats the most rails way to ignore these blank objects?

I dont want validation and errors, just a silent deletion/ignore.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There is a built-in validation:

```
:reject_if => lambda { |c| c[:name].blank? },
```

Comment: Great tip apneadiving, thanks! With that i found this (for anyone else reading)  "You may also set a :reject_if proc to silently ignore any new record hashes if they fail to pass your criteria. For example, the previous example could be rewritten as:" - http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Rails 5 has `reject_if: :all_blank`.  I don't know if this was introduced recently in Rails 5 or if it works in older framework versions also.

Comment: What if I don't wanna `reject`? I wanna `create`/`update` the Profile, but without `favorite_quotes` or `favorite_books`. It doesn't allow it.