# Rails not save association if association values are empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a problem.

I have a Content model that has a polymorphic association, Sponsorship.

In my content form I have a nested form with some sponsorship details. These sponsorship details aren't mandatory, but now every time that I edit a content the sponsorship table is filled with blank data.

I will simplify my code here:

```
class Content < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Sponsorable
end

class Sponsorship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sponsorable, polymorphic: true 
end

module Sponsorable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do

    has_one :sponsorship, as: :sponsorable
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :sponsorship
  end
end
```

I need to clarify that I create an auto-saving feature on my content model, so in my content controller I put a Content.create in the "new" method.

```
def new
    @content = Content.create(author: current_user)
    redirect_to edit_admin_content_path(@content)
end
```

And to fill the sponsorship detail

```
  def edit
    content.build_sponsorship unless content.sponsorship
  end
```

Every time I create and save a content the sponsorship details are created also if I leave the  form fields empty. My content table has a boolean "sponsor": is there a way to save association only if `sponsor == true`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to look at the `reject_if:` option for [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html):

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :sponsorship, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['title'].blank? }
```

Looking up [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963769/accepts-nested-attributes-for-ignore-blank-values) on this matter seem to confirm this.

--

There is also [`reject_if: :all_blank`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods/accepts_nested_attributes_for) -

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :sponsorship, reject_if: :all_blank
```