# Rails 5 optional has_many associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, has-many

app/models/donor.rb

```
has_many :donor_relationships
accepts_nested_attributes_for :donor_relationships, :allow_destroy => true
```

app/models/donor_relationship.rb

```
belongs_to :donor, optional: true
```

I am using `f.fields_for` in donor form and creating `donor` and `donor_relationships` both.

`donor_relationships` is not required must. Issue I face is that when if I not add any donor_relationships then empty record of `donor_relationship` is created with donor id. In rails 4 not like this happen.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[accepts_nested_attributes_for ignore blank values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963769/accepts-nested-attributes-for-ignore-blank-values)

You can add a `reject_if` conditional to the `accepts_nested_attributes` method. Assuming your donor_relationship has an attribute of name (you can go with relationship_id or whatever attribute makes sense):

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :donor_relationships,
                              :allow_destroy => true,
                              :reject_if => lambda { |c| c[:name].blank? }`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reject_if` option:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :donor_relationships, 
  allow_destroy: true,
  reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['important_field'].blank? }
```